# How can I "tranform:translate" relative to a previous translate?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following working code which I am attempting to simplify:

```css
[tt] {
  position: relative;
}
[tt]::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  content: attr(tt);
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
[tt]::before,
[tt]::after {
  position: absolute;
/* Middle 3 */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
/* First 3 */
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(0 , 50%);
}
/* Last 3 */
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(-100%, 50%);
}
/* add animation */
[tt]:hover::before,
[tt]:hover::after {
  animation: tt-move1 100ms ease-out forwards;
  display: block;
}
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3):hover::before,
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3):hover::after {
  animation: tt-move2 100ms ease-out forwards;
}
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3):hover::before,
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3):hover::after {
  animation: tt-move3 100ms ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes tt-move1 {
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes tt-move2 {
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes tt-move3 {
  to {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

/*For working demo*/
div {
  /*won't work unless set relative, Something that happens in [tt]*/
  top:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: black solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div tt="tt1"></div>
<div tt="tt2"></div>
<div tt="tt3"></div>
<div tt="tt4"></div>
<div tt="tt5"></div>
<div tt="tt6"></div>
<div tt="tt7"></div>
<div tt="tt8"></div>
<div tt="tt9"></div>
```

The above code has a specific animation for each different type of element, something which seems unnecessary. To my knowledge, I am simply applying the same transform to each element (moving the element up along the y-axis) so I expected that the following should also work:

```css
[tt] {
  position: relative;
}
[tt]::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  content: attr(tt);
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
[tt]::before,
[tt]::after {
  position: absolute;
/* Middle 3 */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
/* First 3 */
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(0 , 50%);
}
/* Last 3 */
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(-100%, 50%);
}

/*****************Changed code*******************/

/* add animation */
[tt]:hover::before,
[tt]:hover::after {
  animation: tt-move 100ms ease-out forwards;
  display: block;
}
@keyframes tt-move {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
/*///////////////Changed code/////////////////*/

/*For working demo*/
div {
  /*won't work unless set relative, Something that happens in [tt]*/
  top:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: black solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div tt="tt1"></div>
<div tt="tt2"></div>
<div tt="tt3"></div>
<div tt="tt4"></div>
<div tt="tt5"></div>
<div tt="tt6"></div>
<div tt="tt7"></div>
<div tt="tt8"></div>
<div tt="tt9"></div>
```

After some research, I now understand that `transform: translateY(Δy);` is the same as saying `transform: translate(0,Δy);` which is causing the unexpected result.  Unfortunately that was the only method I have been able to find that looks like it is supposed to do what I wanted.

I am looking for a method to `transform:translate` that allows the x-axis of a previous `transform:translate` to stay the same, while only changing the y-axis.

Is there a different way to accomplish this simplification?  Or am I stuck using the repetitious code from above?

Comment: Not without introducing a child element in the `[tt]` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you animate `transform` you have to add any already set values or else they will temporary be overwritten.

In this case you could animate the `bottom` instead, which will give the output you want.

```css
[tt] {
  position: relative;
}
[tt]::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  content: attr(tt);
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
[tt]::before,
[tt]::after {
  position: absolute;
/* Middle 3 */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
/* First 3 */
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(0 , 50%);
}
/* Last 3 */
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::before,
[tt]:nth-last-child(-n+3)::after {
  transform: translate(-100%, 50%);
}

/*****************Changed code*******************/

/* add animation */
[tt]:hover::before,
[tt]:hover::after {
  animation: tt-move 100ms ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes tt-move {
  to {
    bottom: 170%;
  }
}
/*///////////////Changed code/////////////////*/

/*For working demo*/
div {
  /*won't work unless set relative, Something that happens in [tt]*/
  top:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: black solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div tt="tt1"></div>
<div tt="tt2"></div>
<div tt="tt3"></div>
<div tt="tt4"></div>
<div tt="tt5"></div>
<div tt="tt6"></div>
<div tt="tt7"></div>
<div tt="tt8"></div>
<div tt="tt9"></div>
```

Comment: Does this mean there is absolutely no way to use transform while keeping the original transform values?  That doesn't seem very css... I thought unless you replace a value specifically, it shouldn't change it.

Comment: @Enigmadan Yes, that is correct, it won't _keep_ one of the values while changing another. The issue here is that CSS doesn't see `translateX()` and `translateY()` as 2 different properties, they are both a _property value_ for the `transform` property, so when you give it a new value, it overwrites the old value.

Comment: That seems like a bug.  Is there a change being considered for this? Or is it working the way it is meant to?

Comment: How unfortunate.  Thank you for the help.